# Is there anyway to drag actions with dependencies in the Logic App designer?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there anyway to drag actions with dependencies in the Logic App designer?

I can drag/drop some existing actions, e.g. into one of the "if" paths in a Condition

However I have some other actions in a sequence, and I want to move them all into the other path of the Condition.

If I try dragging say the first action in the sequence, I get error ... *"This action cannot be dragged below actions that depend on it"*. And if I try the last action, I get the error  ... *"cannot be dragged above actions"*

But I can't select all of the actions and drag them in a single move

So do I have to re-create my whole sequence within the new "If" path

Comment: Multi-select actions and rearranging is not available currently but on our backlog to get to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there's not easy way to achieve that, but you could probably achieve that by editing the underlying definition much easier.

Comment: Yeap I can manually edit the JSON, but it's not nice ... all too easy to mess up and invalidate the JSON

Comment: well, i don't think there is any other way